# When can leaders lie to their people?

Tags: malchut-royalty, sheker-false

I am looking for Jewish sources that discuss when leaders can justifiably lie to their people for a greater purpose.  (Reasons might be to avoid a panic, to avoid revealing sensitive secrets, to spare their feelings, to fool or avoid informing the enemy, to avoid depressing them when mayhem is unavoidable, and many others.)

I found sources that say one is permitted to lie to save a life, keep the peace, make people feel good, appear humble and modest, and protect oneself from loss or harm.  But nothing on my question.

Comment: Avoid informing the enemy sounds a lot like protecting from harm. Same with a lot of these.

Comment: The problem is that a leader can invoke  "protecting from harm" to justify any lie he chooses to utter.  I am sure our sages tightened that, somewhere.

Comment: Anyone can invoke things wrongly if they aren't careful.

Comment: "I found sources that say one is permitted to lie to save a life, keep the peace, make people feel good, appear humble and modest, and protect oneself from loss or harm." If anyone may lie for these purposes, so too may a leader. Isn't this just a question of scale?

Comment: @Deuteronomy - When so many people are involved, the rules may change.